Adding test cases to camel routes with saga
I'm currently stuck on a test case for camel route with saga, whenever i call the saga routeId with adviceWith, i get an error saying "exchange is not part of saga" and when I try using routeId of the camel route, i get the error saying: there are no outputs which natches: direct:updateDoc in the route: Route(updateDoc) [From[direct:updateDoc]-> [Saga[compensation:.... Error
I tried adding routeId to the route i needed testing, did the same for saga but when utilizing those i get error

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
